# Django effective way to use prefetch_related or select_related

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I regularly use `prefetch_related` & `select_related` to process nested queries in one go.
I would like you to know what we can do more to make it a little more faster.

`Foo.objects.prefetch_related('bar')`

There are some cases in my application where I just need only particular columns if `Bar` model.

Does using custom queryset in `prefetch_related` method like below,  boost the speed of the query?

```
Foo.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('bar',queryset=Bar.objects.all().only('id')))
```

Comment: It would increase the speed of the query because you are returning less data. If you access any attributes of the Bar objects that you have not included in the call to only then you will perform additional queries

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your second argument, How do I make sure to not to make any additional queries?